# Modifying Excel with Angular/node

Tags: node.js, excel, angular

My excel sheets are messy and huge, I want to read them on a local angular page to make it look pretty and do some basic UI things. I'm pretty sure it's going to only be run off Ng serve locally, but I'm having trouble accessing the Excel files on my computer and saving them in the same files.

Can Angular access the local excel sheets? If so how? (I would prefer the path be saved and I wouldn't have to click upload and find the file each time. ) also, I don't want a new excel file each time it's modified I want it saved into the same file.

I think I might have to use node to read the sheet, pass it as a JSON, load that up on angular and modify it. Then use node to save it. Or something like that because I can't seem to find a way to change excel files in angular. I'm very new to this so I don't know if that flow works.

EDIT: I was planning to have the excel sheet converted to a JSON, then just read that data and do some formatting to make it look nice, but that isn't really the issue, its more the I/o problem

Comment: This question is incomplete, as you are not saying how you want the data of the Excel, which type of component you are planning to use or how you even are going to present it. 
As what I suggest is to first investigate how are you planning to show your data in angular and what type of component serves you best for your purpose

Comment: @ZetaPR I thought I addressed that in the third paragraph, saying I wanted it to be a JSON, but it doesn't matter as long as I can read it and redisplay it, then modify it and send it back.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what is being asked, this is to parse a local excel file, located somewhere in the application such as the 'assets' folder for example you would need to implement a library such as SheetJS who serves all the purposes and in the end transform the xlsx to JSON. 
Official documentation: https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs
TypeScript demo: https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/tree/master/demos/typescript

To implement it:

```
 import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

 const { read, utils: { sheet_to_json } } = XLSX;

 export function readFirstSheet(data: any, options: XLSX.ParsingOptions): any[][] {
   const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = read(data, options);
   const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]];
   return sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1, raw: true });
 }
```